# How to use indexOf() with linq query to get case insensitive data?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq, expression

I am working on .net project with C# where i am using report to show students data.
I am providing searching on all fields and using dynamic field in where clause at run time.
I am using Student,Class,State,City as entity model class and Filter is class which has multiple column search value.
Here are my code.

```
public class Student{
    public string id{get;set;}
    public string first_name{get;set;}
    public string last_name{get;set;}
    public string address{get;set;}
    public string class{get;set;}
.....
}
public class StudentModel{
    public string Student_Id{get;set;}
    public string name{get;set;}
    public string class{get;set;}
    public string class_teacher{get;set;}
    public string city{get;set;}
    public string country{get;set;}
   
}
var student_list=(from r in Student where (r.is_deleted == 0) select r).ToList();
var class_list=(from r in Class where (r.is_deleted == 0) select r).ToList();
var city_list=(from r in City where (r.is_deleted == 0) select r).ToList();
var state_list=(from r in State where (r.is_deleted == 0) select r).ToList();

 List<Filter> filterList = new ArrayList();
   filterList.add(new Filter("StudentId","Xc"));
   filterList.add(new Filter("name","ab"));

var deleg = ExpressionBuilder.GetExpression<StudentModel>(filterList).Compile();

list = (from stu in student_list
      join cls in class_list on stu.id equals cls.student_id
      join cty in city_list on stu.id equals cty.student_id into city from City in cty.DefaultIfEmpty()
      join st in state_list on  stu.id equals cty.st into sta from State in sta.DefaultIfEmpty()

      select new StudentModel
      {
        StudentId = stu.Student_Id,
        name=stu.first_name,
        class=cls.class,
        class_teacher = cls.class_teacher,
        city=cty.city
        country=st.country
         }).Where(deleg).ToList();
     
 public class Filter
    { 
        
        [JsonProperty("name")]
        public string name { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("searchValue")]
        public string searchValue  { get; set; }

       Filter(string name,string searchValue){
         this.name=name;
         this.searchValue=searchValue;
        }
    }
```

Here I referred  https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/582450/Build-Where-Clause-Dynamically-in-Linq  to use expression with contains, startWith etc. but my problem is that I want to use indexOf() in searching because contains() method is case sensitive and I want case insensitive search.

Here are my code:-

```
    public class ExpressionBuilder
    {
        private static MethodInfo indexOfMethod = typeof(string).GetMethod("IndexOf", new Type[] { typeof(string) });


        public static Expression<Func<T,bool>> GetExpression<T>(IList<Filter> filters)
        {
            if (filters.Count == 0)
                return null;

            ParameterExpression param = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T), "t");
            Expression exp = null;

            if (filters.Count == 1)
                exp = GetExpression<T>(param, filters[0]);
            else if (filters.Count == 2)
                exp = GetExpression<T>(param, filters[0], filters[1]);
            else
            {
                while (filters.Count > 0)
                {
                    var f1 = filters[0];
                    var f2 = filters[1];

                    if (exp == null)
                        exp = GetExpression<T>(param, filters[0], filters[1]);
                    else
                        exp = Expression.AndAlso(exp, GetExpression<T>(param, filters[0], filters[1]));

                    filters.Remove(f1);
                    filters.Remove(f2);

                    if (filters.Count == 1)
                    {
                        exp = Expression.AndAlso(exp, GetExpression<T>(param, filters[0]));
                        filters.RemoveAt(0);
                    }
                }
            }

            return Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(exp, param);
        }

        private static Expression GetExpression<T>(ParameterExpression param, Filter filter)
        {
            MemberExpression member = Expression.Property(param, filter.name);
            ConstantExpression constant = Expression.Constant(filter.searchValue);            
           return Expression.Call(member, indexOfMethod, constant);
           
        }

        private static BinaryExpression GetExpression<T>
        (ParameterExpression param, Filter filter1, Filter filter2)
        {
            Expression bin1 = GetExpression<T>(param, filter1);
            Expression bin2 = GetExpression<T>(param, filter2);

            return Expression.AndAlso(bin1, bin2);
        }
}
```

But I am getting error is :`Expression of type 'System.Int32' cannot be used for return type 'System.Boolean'-`

Please suggest me.

Comment: Your code lacks a bit on [mre] department. What is `Filter`. What is `Class`, `Student`, etc in your LINQ query?

Comment: If you'r on .NET Core or .NET 5+, there is a [String.Contrains overload](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.contains?view=net-8.0#system-string-contains(system-string-system-stringcomparison)) supporting case-insensitive search

Comment: Please add clarity to your question by noting the Version of .Net/c# in use.

Answer (score 0):

Without a repro it is hard to actually tell, but at least `GetExpression<T>(ParameterExpression param, Filter filter)` looks suspicious, it should represent expression returning boolean. try targeting `string.Contains` method accepting `StringComparison`:

```cs
private static MethodInfo containsMethod = typeof(string)
            .GetMethod(nameof(string.Contains),
                new Type[] { typeof(string), typeof(StringComparison) });
private static Expression GetExpression<T>(ParameterExpression param, Filter filter)
{
    MemberExpression member = Expression.Property(param, filter.name);
    ConstantExpression constant = Expression.Constant(filter.searchValue);

    return Expression.Call(member, containsMethod, constant,
        Expression.Constant(StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase));
}
```

**UPD**

For older framework you will need to create expression like `"str".IndexOf("assa") > 0`. For example for case-insensitive comparison you can try something like:

```cs
private static MethodInfo indexOfStringComparerMethod = typeof(string)
    .GetMethod(nameof(string.IndexOf), new Type[]
    {
        typeof(string),
        typeof(StringComparison)
    });

private static Expression GetExpression<T>(ParameterExpression param, Filter filter)
{
    MemberExpression member = Expression.Property(param, filter.name);
    ConstantExpression constant = Expression.Constant(filter.searchValue);
    var call = Expression.Call(member, indexOfStringComparerMethod, constant,
        Expression.Constant(StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase));
        
    return Expression.GreaterThanOrEqual(call, Expression.Constant(0));
}
```

Note that it is highly likely this will not work in case of ORM, but for ORM case you can try to use the "original" `IndexOf` with one parameter.

Comment: "Without a repro it is hard to actually tell," agree, so why encourage poorly asked questions rather than vote to add clarity to them?

Comment: @guru Stron :- the containsMethod object giving null value.

Comment: @santosh what .NET version are you using?

Comment: @guru Stron :-4.5